# Restler RC3 Install

Tags: installation, restler

Is there a way to 'copy and paste' the RC3 to my host without having to run 'make composer-install'? Unfortunately my host is lousy and doesn't allow for this.

Restler 2 was as easy to install as putting the files into a directory and making a few config changes. That doesn't appear to be the case anymore. I love Restler 2 but need the functionality offered in RC3.

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm in the same boat 5yrs after this question was asked.  While the answers may be accurate, they don't answer the question.  "Is there a way to cut and paste..."  I'm starting my 2nd week of trying to install RC3 with composer and everything else it needs, and still nothing works.  How to get a folder that uses supplied examples like "BMI" would be worth ALL my reputation points here. :(

Answer (score 3):

With Restler3, Yes! you can do that and it still works fine for JSON and XML format. `make composer-install` is only necessary for Plist, Yaml and AMF formats as they depend on some third party libraries (which you will be able to automatically update independent of Restler 3 with the help of composer) also it installs latest version of [Restler API Explorer](https://github.com/Luracast/Restler-API-Explorer).

If you need those formats and / or API Explorer, you can download restler on your machine and run `make composer-install` locally (It does not need a web server) and then upload the resulting folders to your server

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize I had needed to also upgrade to >5.3. Initially only had blank screens and then got so obsessed with make composer-install that I hadn't tried it after the upgrade. It would seem API Explorer is working on the Access example. Again thanks.

Comment: Thanks to you, we have updated the README to highlight these facts. Please mark it as the right answer so that those who read this question in the future will know it has been answered

Answer (score 0):

Install the system at localhost or at a virtual host, and then transfer all the files to your host :)